# StyleCop no longer shows "Show Help" context sensitive menu

Tags: visual-studio, stylecop

I used to be able to click on a StyleCop warning and select a "Show Help Menu" which would show me more info about the warning.

Can anyone suggest why I am not seeing it now?

[image]D:\Users\UserName\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#

Answer (score 1):

Some warnings provide a description, others may not. Maybe the documentation is just incomplete or the authors figure some warnings don't need additional clarification?

Answer (score 0):

If stylecop check is been run during a build (MSBuild/VS build) the show help option wont appear, however if you right click on the solution and run stylecop check, it will have the show help option.

Hope that helps